# How can I copy folder with IF Condition?

Tags: java, ant

I'd like to copy files and subdirectories using Ant from a single subdirectory without copying the rest of the directory structure and contents. For example, I'd like to copy  "dir_1" ,"dir_2" ,"dir_3" ," dir_4" ,but one of the "file_1" or "file_2" By A Static Name Like "MY_NAME". I think I have write a Condition Statement ,For example :

```
if(MY_NAME==file_1)
  then copy file_1 , to Folder
if(MY_Name==file_2)
  then copy FILE_2 to Folder
```

Is there a pattern that I can use to do this?

```
 temp
 \--dir_1
 \--dir_2
 \--dir_3
  |
  \--dir_4
  \--dir_5
     |
     \--file_1
     \--file_2
```

Comment: Can you use multipe [Copy ANT Target](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) with fileset section to copy selected files? If you want to use 'if', you need to check [AntContrib library](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html)

Comment: I couldn,t solve this problem yet